# Web scraping an interactive chart

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I see that there are a few posts on this, but each situation is apparently unique.  I'm trying to get the data behind the chart on this page:  https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-VOLI/

It's a fairly obscure market index and it isn't available through Yahoo, which is where I usually look (specifically `web.DataReader` in python) and this is one of the few spots that appears to have the full set of daily prices.

```
<script nonce="XL1oARYPz8X2tvqk">
    window.__defaultsOverrides = {
        'mainSeriesProperties.style': 3,
        'mainSeriesProperties.areaStyle.priceSource': 'close',
        'scalesProperties.lineColor': 'rgba( 76, 82, 94, 1)',
        'scalesProperties.showSymbolLabels': false,
        'scalesProperties.textColor': 'rgba( 76, 82, 94, 1)',
        'scalesProperties.seriesLastValueMode': 0,
        'paneProperties.topMargin': 13,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showStudyArguments': false,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showStudyTitles': false,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showStudyValues': false,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showSeriesTitle': false,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showSeriesOHLC': true,
        'paneProperties.legendProperties.showLegend': false,
    };
</script>
```

This is what shows as the element related to the chart and it's frankly a little over my head in terms of web development since it's just a script tag (i.e., it's not merely a subelement of the chart element - it is the chart element).  I tried searching for the nonce value of `XL1oARYPz8X2tvqk` in the JS files and don't see anything that looks like it would be populating the chart.

I'd think that I'd be able to find the chart data somewhere in the window object, but I'm not seeing it.  Is there an easy way to track this down?  I know I can use an interactive scraper, but it seems like it has to be easier than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is retrieved from a websocket connection on :

```
wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=symbols%2FNASDAQ-VOLI%2F
```

You may get those data by sending commands and receiving data from this websocket. You can see all messages received and sent from Chrome development console :

[image: websocket console screenshot]

The format is a stream of JSON objects (can be multiple objects per response) with some prefix like `~m~23+~m~`. So it's necessary to split the response with a regex (the number at the middle changes)

You see a lot of messages to send in the screenshot above (green messages) but we are only interested by those using the "chart session token" eg the commands that control chart and not quotes

The following messages are sent at the beginning :

```
{"m": "set_data_quality", "p": ["low"]},
{"m": "set_auth_token", "p": ["unauthorized_user_token"]},
{"m":"chart_create_session","p":[chartSession,""]},
{"m":"resolve_symbol","p":[chartSession,"symbol_1","={\"symbol\":\"NASDAQ:VOLI\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}"]},
{"m":"create_series","p":[chartSession,"s1","s1","symbol_1","D",300]},
{"m":"switch_timezone","p":[chartSession,"Etc/UTC"]},
{"m":"resolve_symbol","p":[chartSession,"symbol_2","={\"symbol\":\"NASDAQ:VOLI\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}"]},
{"m":"modify_series","p":[chartSession,"s1","s2","symbol_2","D,12M"]},
```

After that, you receive a response with a message with value `timescale_update` with the chart data and more

The following script starts the websocket connection, sends the initial messages required to get the chart data and builds a graph using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) that is saved as a png :

```
import json 
import websockets
import urllib
import asyncio
import re
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

wsParams = {
    "from": "symbols/NASDAQ-VOLI/"
}
websocketUri = f"wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?{urllib.parse.urlencode(wsParams)}"

result = []
chartSession = "cs_Dj1BV8ochLL0"

initMessages = [
    {"m": "set_data_quality", "p": ["low"]},
    {"m": "set_auth_token", "p": ["unauthorized_user_token"]},
    {"m":"chart_create_session","p":[chartSession,""]},
    {"m":"resolve_symbol","p":[chartSession,"symbol_1","={\"symbol\":\"NASDAQ:VOLI\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}"]},
    {"m":"create_series","p":[chartSession,"s1","s1","symbol_1","D",300]},
    {"m":"switch_timezone","p":[chartSession,"Etc/UTC"]},
    {"m":"resolve_symbol","p":[chartSession,"symbol_2","={\"symbol\":\"NASDAQ:VOLI\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}"]},
    {"m":"modify_series","p":[chartSession,"s1","s2","symbol_2","D,12M"]},
]

def strip(text):
    noDataReg = re.match('~m~\d+~m~~h~\d+', text, re.MULTILINE)
    if not noDataReg:
        dataReg = re.split('~m~\d+~m~', text)
        return [json.loads(t) for t in dataReg if t]
    return []

def unstrip(text):
    return f"~m~{len(text)-8}~m~{json.dumps(text)}"

async def init(websocket):
    for m in initMessages:
        await websocket.send(unstrip(m))

async def startReceiving(websocket):
    data = await websocket.recv()
    print(strip(data))
    await init(websocket)
    while(True):
        data = await websocket.recv()
        payloads = strip(data)
        for p in payloads:
            if p["m"] == "timescale_update":
                dates = [
                    datetime.fromtimestamp(t["v"][0])
                    for t in p["p"][1]["s1"]["s"]
                ]
                values = [
                    t["v"][4]
                    for t in p["p"][1]["s1"]["s"]
                ]
                plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
                plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=25))
                plt.plot(dates, values)
                plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
                plt.ylabel('VOLI Index Chart')
                plt.xlabel('Date')
                plt.savefig("voli.png")
        print(payloads)

async def websocketConnect():
    async with websockets.client.connect(websocketUri, extra_headers= {
            "Origin": "https://www.tradingview.com"
        }) as websocket:
        print(f'started websocket')
        await startReceiving(websocket)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())
```

[Try this on repl.it (without the matplotlib part)](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/WebsocketData)

And the generated chart :

[image: generated chart image using matploptlib]

Some note :

- In order to successfully connect to the websocket server you need to send the `Origin` header with the correct value otherwise it returns 403
- the chart session token is hardcoded here but it can be anything, it seems to be generated randomly on the website (with a regex pattern)
- I've removed all websocket messages about quotes, you'll need to add those kind of message to receive notifications about "real time" value changes (to be added to init messages) :

  ```
  {"m":"quote_create_session","p":["qs_QrddDPrS65gC"]}

  {"m":"quote_add_symbols","p":["qs_QrddDPrS65gC","NASDAQ:VOLI",{"flags":["force_permission"]}]}
  ```

Note that `quote_create_session` is necessary with a new session token (!= from the chart session token). Then you'll receive notifications via websocket

- if you want to receive notifications, note that there is a keep alive which closes the websocket automatically if you don't send anything for x period of time. You just need to send the following command periodically :

  ```
  ~m~4~m~~h~1
  ```

Comment: I'll need to experiment some, but this is excellent - thanks.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah also you can investigate with [wscat](https://github.com/websockets/wscat) using `wscat -c "wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=symbols%2FNASDAQ-VOLI%2F" -H "Origin: https://www.tradingview.com"`